# Trying to install Latex Package l3backend from CTAN

Tags: packages

I have installed this package, but can not get it to work. I notice there is a l3backend.ins file. When going to the command prompt and typing, latex l3backend.ins I get the error message, I can not find the file l3docstrip.dxt. I have moved the file around, such as trying in downloads folder, versus desktop, versus in the latex folder. I have never successfully downloaded a package before, so I am just going off of youtube videos and stuff. I am trying to do this to create a resume, and was trying to download the code off of overleaf, so I can just have it for whenever.

Comment: l3backend isn't something that you should install manually and as single file. It depends on the rest of the l3kernel. Why don't you use the package manager of your tex system?

Comment: There is a ready-to-install TDS-style zip on CTAN if you _really_ need it: http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/l3backend.tds.zip

Comment: I see that this link contains the correct information. Would I then add it to my latex folder and will it work? I notice it still has the .ins file instead of the .stl file. My original error was l3backend-pdfmode.def not found. But this package contained it. So that is why I downloaded it manually. I can not get it to correctly download manually though. When going to your file and entering latex l3backend.ins I got the same error can not find l3docstrip.dtx. So it did not change the .ins file like I was expecting.